# Java Regex for Valid Directory Path

Tags: java, regex

I enter from the console the path to the directory in which I want to search for certain files. I need a regex that only matches directory paths, not file paths. For example,

`"C:\directory", "C:\directory\another", "D:\directory\", "D:\"` must match.

`"C:\directory\file.txt", "D:\another.pdf"`   should not match.

Comment: [The regex seem to match files in subpaths as well](https://regex101.com/r/rt4Vxv/1). But it seems also to match other paths, e.g. paths ending in a `\ `. For me, the question is unclear. Please [edit] the post and specify what exactly  the requirements are.

Comment: Please be aware that dots in folder names are perfectly valid in Windows.  There's nothing illegal about having a folder called `c:\my.txt`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) as well as [`regular-expression.info`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) might be valuable resources.

Comment: ```File.isDirectory```  seems to be what you're reaching for ... (which would solve the problem that @DawoodibnKareem rightly brings up)

Comment: Thanks everybody. Especially, @g00se. Your solution is just what I've been looking for!

Comment: :) Or ```java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory```

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating a directory called `C:\directory\file.txt`, similarly, `C:\directory\another` is also valid as a file name, not just a directory. Don't apply arbitrary rules that don't exist for the underlying problem.